# Adding n number of items to a room class

Tags: java, oop

I'm working through a programming book for class. The current project is a terminal based adventure game.

Currently I have everything compiling and the program does run but it returns 'null' for the item description.

How do I go about actually putting the items specified in the item class into rooms / make it so that rooms are created with items inside?
Is there a way to get this to be done randomly?

below is my item class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Item
{
    private String idescription;
    private int iweight;
    private HashMap items;

    public Item(String idescription, int iweight)
    {
        this.idescription = idescription;
        this.iweight = iweight;
        items=new HashMap();
    }

    private void addItems()
    {
        items.put("flier", new Item("there is a flier for a club on the floor",
                    0));
        items.put("baccy", new Item("there is a pouch of tobacco on\n" + 
            "the table, your friends say you may help yourself if you can find\n" + 
            "rolling papers, filter tips and a lighter.",2));
        //...
    }
}
```

This is my Room class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Room 
{
    private String rdescription;
    private HashMap<String, Room> exits;
    private HashMap items;
    private Item itemroom;
    private Item item;

    public Room(String rdescription) 
    {
        items = new HashMap();
        this.rdescription = rdescription;
        exits = new HashMap<String, Room>(); //creates the rooms   
    }

    public void addItems(String item_name, String idescription, int iweight)
    {
        items.put(item_name, new Item(idescription, iweight));
    }

    public void setExits(String direction, Room neighbour)
    {
        exits.put(direction, neighbour);
    }

    public Room getExit(String direction)
    {
        return exits.get(direction);
    }

    public String getExitString()
    {
        String returnString = "Exits: ";
        Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit: keys)
        {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return rdescription;
    }

    public String getLongDescription()
    {
        return "You are at the" + rdescription + ".\n" + 
            getExitString()+". \n" + 
            items.getIdescription();
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help. Still very much a beginner and going through many phases of utter panic and confusion.

Comment: Isn't there any possible way you could have just provided the necessary code involving the question, rather than slapping everyone in the face with huge code blocks? Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: While @austinwernli 's words may be a little bit harsh, I tend to agree. There surely is a solution for your problem but this IS too much code for such a question. Please try to boil down the code to the essential parts and I am sure you will get some useful comments/answers.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I wasn't sure whether people would want more or less code if it might help explain the issue etc.
I shall be more concise in the future :).

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your code, a common mistake for beginners it to over-complicate things. From what I can make out, rooms are supposed to contain items. So, we have 2 classes: `Room` and `Item`.

The minimum for the `Room` class could be something like this:

```
public class Room {

  private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

  public void addItem(Item item) {
    items.add(item);
  }

  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
  }
}
```

That way, the Room contais a list of Items and has methods allowing you to add an item, or list the items.

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this problem. It is quite a bit of code to go through. My logic was instead create a `ItemList` class that houses all of the different items. You can add methods to add a new item to the list of available items or delete an existing item. Then I would just make methods to return a random `Item` or `List<Item>` and then just call these methods from your room class. Something like this:

```
public class ItemList {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private void addItems(){
        //I would keep this the same but instead put them in the itemList variable
        items.add(new Item());
    }
    public Item randomItem(){
        return items.get(new Random().nextInt(items.size()));
    }
    public List<Item> randomItemList(int numOfRandomItems){
        List<Item> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<numOfRandomItems; i++){
            output.add(randomItem());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
class Item{
    //Made these public for example. I would continue using constructor, get/set for the fields.
    String idescription;
    int iweight;
}
```

With this, you can even set it up so that rooms have different `ItemList` so different rooms can choose a random item from different lists. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to be nitpicky, naming a variable `itemList` is bad practice. You should not have the variable type in the name. `items` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @JasonPortnoy thanks for the input. I agree. I had it as `items` took a step back from the code and it looked confusing seeing the difference between `items` and `item` when skimming fast. That is why I went with `itemList`. In real practice I would have moved the `item` class to its own class file and named it `items`. I will go ahead and change it though.